# Variables plotted weirdly in a dendrogram (ClustOfVar for R)

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I plotted a dendrogram using plot(hclustervar(X.quali=data)) from the R package ClustOfVar because I wanted to explore the structure behind the survey responses. All variables were coded as factors, some of them were ordered (e.g. always, often, sometimes).

The circled part of the plot looks weird. It doesn't show where the 5 variables belong. Why does it do that? Where's the source of the problem? Can anyone please let me know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

[image: Dendrogram plotted using plot(hclustvar(X.quali=data))]

Comment: It's not a bug but a result of the algorithm. For some reason it decided that some children are higher than the parents. Why it dod that require understanding the algorithm.

Comment: This is called "reverse". Look for "dendrogram reverses" on this site.

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much!